# error using CAddTable and ConcatTable in torch

Tags: machine-learning, lua, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, torch

I tried to build a few residual blocks  in my  networks using torch, but why torch just gives me errors when using CAddTable and ConcatTable. Could anyone please give some advice? Thanks in advance. The code I use is here:

```
a=image.load('test.png')
input=torch.Tensor(1,3,60,60)
input[1]=a
input=input:cuda()
local conv_block_1 = nn.Sequential()
conv_block_1:add(cudnn.SpatialConvolution(3, 16, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2))--  ,(60+2*2-5)/1+1=60
conv_block_1:add(cudnn.SpatialBatchNormalization(16))
conv_block_1:add(cudnn.ReLU(true))

local conv_block_2 = nn.Sequential()
conv_block_2:add(cudnn.SpatialConvolution(16, 32, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2)) -- (60+2*2-5)/1+1=60
conv_block_2:add(cudnn.SpatialBatchNormalization(32))
conv_block_2:add(cudnn.ReLU(true))

local conv_block_3 = nn.Sequential()
conv_block_3:add(cudnn.SpatialConvolution(32, 16, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2))  -- (60+2*2-5)/1+1=60
conv_block_3:add(cudnn.SpatialBatchNormalization(16))
conv_block_3:add(cudnn.ReLU(true))

local concat_block_1 = nn.ConcatTable()
concat_block_1:add(conv_block_1)  ----
concat_block_1:add(conv_block_3 )

local add_block_1 = nn.Sequential()
add_block_1:add(concat_block_1)
add_block_1:add(nn.CAddTable(true))
add_block_1:add(cudnn.ReLU(true))

local model=nn.Sequential()
model:add(conv_block_1)

model:add(conv_block_2)
model:add(conv_block_3)
model:add(add_block_1)
model:cuda()
model:forward(input)
```

and the error reads like this:
...torch/install/share/lua/5.1/cudnn/SpatialConvolution.lua:102: input has to contain: 3 feature maps, but received input of size: 1 x 16 x 60 x 60
stack traceback:

Comment: I think the error is in the network architecture. Input (3 feature maps[FM]) -> conv_block1 (16 FM) -> conv_block2 (32FM) -> conv_block3 (16FM) -> conv_block1(3FM) when the output of conv_block3 is 16 FM.

Comment: But what I want is just CAdd the outputs of conv_block_1 and conv_block_3, they are both 16FM, where is the error?

Comment: Doing `print (model.modules)` you can see how your network is connected. First three `nn.sequential` blocks are `conv_block_1`, `conv_block_2` and `conv_block_3`, respectively. The output of `conv_block_3` is directly connected to the concat table which has `conv_block_3` and `conv_block_1` inside. So the output of `conv_block_3` (16 feature maps [FM]) is going directly to the concat table which is accepting the input values `conv_block_1` (3 FM) and `conv_block_3` (32 FM). In the connection from the first `conv_block_3` to the concat table is where you are getting the error.

Comment: So how to fix this?

Comment: How to CAdd the two 16 feature maps?